# Nested For Loops in R for Large Data Sets

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

I have three variables of different lengths title and content have about 85,000 rows and tag has about 15,000. For both title and content I want to see if each row contains a tag and if it does contain the tag add it to a new variables titletag and contenttag. I then want to combine titletag and contenttag to creat testtag so that all the tags in titletag[i] and contenttag[i] are in the new variable testtag[i].

I'm using R. The problem I'm having is that the code I have runs without errors for creating titletag and content tag, but when I go to combine them it says that neither variable exists. My code is:

```
for (i in 1:length(tag)) 
  {for (j in 1:length(title)) 
  {ifelse(tag[i] %in% title[j],titletag[] <- tag[i]," ") 
    ifelse(tag[i] %in% content[j],contenttag[] <- tag[i]," ")}}
testtag <- cbind(titletag, contenttag)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please illustrate with data so we can better understand and reproduce. What is *content*?

Comment: Some of the data in title is: [1] "What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?"     
[2] "What is your simplest explanation of the string theory?"
[3] "Lie theory, Representations and particle physics"       
[4] "Will Determinism be ever possible?"                     
[5] "Hamilton's Principle"                                   
[6] "What is sound and how is it produced?"

Comment: Some of the data in tag is: [1] "caribbean"       "cruising"        "vacations"       "guides"          "extreme-tourism"
[6] "amazon-river"